# xamarin.forms Feed datasource into view from data template from code

Tags: xamarin.forms

I build this expandable view like so:

```
                <expandable:ExpandableView 
                    x:Name="expandableView"  
                    TouchHandlerView="{x:Reference arrow}"
                    CommandParameter="some text"
                    Command="{Binding Path=TapCommand, Source={x:Reference page}}"
                    ExpandAnimationLength="100">

                    <expandable:ExpandableView.PrimaryView>
                        <Label x:Name="arrow" Text="down"/>
                    </expandable:ExpandableView.PrimaryView>

                    <expandable:ExpandableView.SecondaryViewTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ListView x:Name="list_cat1">
                                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <ViewCell>
                                            <StackLayout>
                                                <Label Text="{Binding subCatName}" >
                                                    <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="GetClick"/>
                                                    </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                                </Label>
                                            </StackLayout>
                                        </ViewCell>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <!--
                                <ListView.ItemsSource>
                                    <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                                        <x:String>mono</x:String>
                                        <x:String>monodroid</x:String>
                                        <x:String>monotouch</x:String>
                                        <x:String>monorail</x:String>
                                        <x:String>monodevelop</x:String>
                                        <x:String>monotone</x:String>
                                        <x:String>monopoly</x:String>
                                        <x:String>monomodal</x:String>
                                        <x:String>mononucleosis</x:String>
                                    </x:Array>
                                </ListView.ItemsSource>
                                -->
                            </ListView>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </expandable:ExpandableView.SecondaryViewTemplate>

                </expandable:ExpandableView>
```

First, I gave it data via the itemsource from the xaml. This worked and I even got the correct click event assigned to it.

Now I wanna feed data from code. Unfortunately, I cannot access: x:Name in listview. It doesnt exist in code.

How can I feed a list of data into this expandable view?

Thank you!

Comment: set the ListView ItemsSource in code

Comment: I cant, because i cannot reference the name of the listview.

Comment: I'm not familiar with ExpandableView, does it have an ItemsSource?

Comment: Well, you see that i am giving it an itemsource from the xaml, but i cannot access this in code.

Comment: Yes, because it's inside of a template.  I didn't ask about the ListView, I asked if the **ExpandableView** had an ItemsSource

Comment: So, how would I access it? I mean, when it works in xmal it must work from code, right?

Comment: Hi, what is the `expandable:ExpandableView`, could you share the source code or link?